# Tomcat out of memory heapdump setup

Tags: tomcat, configuration

For an unknown reason Apache Tomcat goes out of memory.
Tomcat runs as a service.
What I already tried to do was adding:

```
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=<path-to-heap-dump-file>
```

But this didn't generate a dump. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which user is starting tomcat and what file-system right on it?
you can try to set:

```
-XX:HeapDumpPath=/tmp/java.dump
```

Are you really sure that tomcat uses this parameters?

`$ps -auxww|grep java`

Try to review the Tomcat parameters.

Comment: Is it intentional that this answer does not mention `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` (that is presented in the original question)?